# Is there a way to alias formula blocks for later use in the same formula in MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office

Is it possible to alias a formula block and refer to it later in the same formula? For example, suppose I have an IF expression and the logical test component is a complex formula in itself which I would like to use again if the test evaluates to false, like this:

```
=IF(Do_this()=0,"NA",Do_this())
```

Answer (score 1):

***If you have Excel O365*** you can use the LET() function, or you can use the LAMBDA() function in the Name Manager to accomplish this.

**LET()**

Using both the LET() function AND alt-enter to create non-breaking carriage returns in your formulas, allows you to accomplish two objectives at once:

- Simplify formulas for better readability and thus better future maintainability;
- Optimize performance by calculating a value only once and re-using it in the formula.

Let's say your "Do_This" was a formula that did 3 "XLOOKUPs" of a player name that is in cell A1 and summed the values found in a score table:

```
=LET(
score1, XLOOKUP(A1, scoreTable1[players], scoreTable1[scores], 0),
score2, XLOOKUP(A1, scoreTable2[players], scoreTable1[scores], 0),
score3, XLOOKUP(A1, scoreTable3[players], scoreTable1[scores], 0),
totalScore, score1 + score2 + score3,
If( totalScore = 0, “NA”, totalScore )
)
```

Easily readable, understandable, and it separates *HOW* to gather the data from the logic of *WHAT* to do with the data once gathered.  The 3 lookups are performed only once, instead of twice, which can be *very* significant to performance on a large complex sheet.

**LAMBDA in Name Manager**

Also requires O365.  You can now go into Name Manager and create a function using the `LAMBDA()` function.  You could define a function `GetTotalScore()` using Lambda, and then in your cell formula you'd just have the logic:

```
=IF( GetTotalScore(A1) = 0, "NA", GetTotalScore(A1) )
```

One you've defined the name, you can just use `=GetTotalScore("Joe Smith")` exactly like `GetTotalScore()` was a built-in function.

The way I did the if above  invokes the function twice, so if all you want is readability and not better performance, that's OK.  But you can go a step farther and still use LET() *and* a named LAMBDA:

```
=LET(
totalScore, getTotalScore(A1),
IF( totalScore = 0, "NA", totalScore )
)
```

Now you've invoked the formula only once AND have readable code.

And finally, remember that you can "build" complex LAMBDAs in the Name Manager.  This is useful when formulas get wickedly complex:

- Define a Lambda getScore1
- Define another Lambda getScore2
- Define another Lambda getScore3
- Define a totalScore Lambda that adds them together.